# Having a problem with the accumulator loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to run multiple scenarios by changing the starting tuition, annual increase, and/or the number of years to graduation in my program. With the output looking like this:

```
Mark
Starting Semester Tuition: $1,020
Year 1: $1040.40
Year 2: $1061.21
Year 3: $1072.43
```

But I'm getting stuck at my accumulator loop.

```
## Calculate tution over the years until graduton
TimeUntilGrad = int(TimeUntilGrad)
CurrentAnnTuition = float(CurrentAnnTuition)

for Tuition in range(1, TimeUntilGrad):
    TuitionAmount = CurrentAnnTuition *  ProjectAnnIncrease + CurrentAnnTuition
    TuitionAmount = TuitionAmount * ProjectAnnIncrease + TuitionAmount
    TuitionAmount += Tuition

            
### Display results to user
print(UserName , '\n'' Starting Semester Tuition: ' , (CurrentAnnTuition,),
     '\n''Tuition over the years until graduation: ', (Tuition, TuitionAmount))
```

My outputs always end up looking like this:

```
Mark 
Starting Semester Tuition: (1020.0,) 
Tuition over the years until graduation: (3, 1106.232)
```

Comment: You're getting stuck how? I see code, and desired results, but you haven't actually described the problem.

Comment: My outputs when I run the code look like this:                                                                       
  Mark 
 Starting Semester Tuition:  (1020.0,) 
Tuition over the years until graduation:  (3, 1106.232)

Comment: put all information in question, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: you have wrong indentations and `print()` is executed after `for`-loop but it should be inside `for`-loop. OR you should keep `Tuition, TuitionAmount` on list and later use `for`-loop to display all `Tuition, TuitionAmount` from this list.

Comment: One minor tip: the line `TuitionAmount = TuitionAmount * ProjectAnnIncrease + TuitionAmount` can be rewritten simply as `TuitionAmount *= (1.0 + ProjectAnnIncrease)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `print` inside `for`-loop like this

```
print(UserName)
#print('Starting Semester Tuition:', CurrentAnnTuition)
#print('Starting Semester Tuition: ${:,}'.format(CurrentAnnTuition))
print(f'Starting Semester Tuition: ${CurrentAnnTuition:,}')

for Tuition in range(1, TimeUntilGrad):
     TuitionAmount = CurrentAnnTuition *  ProjectAnnIncrease + CurrentAnnTuition
     TuitionAmount = TuitionAmount * ProjectAnnIncrease + TuitionAmount
     TuitionAmount += Tuition
     #print('Tuition over the years until graduation:', (Tuition, TuitionAmount))
     #print('Year {}: ${:.2f}'.format(Tuition, TuitionAmount))
     print(f'Year {Tuition}: ${TuitionAmount:.2f}')
```

---

**BTW:** I don't know if calculations are correct but it may need other changes.